# Solr 6.6 + highlight stem of word

Tags: solr, stemming, solr-query-syntax, porter-stemmer

I'm pretty new to Solr.  I was reading the Solr highlighting documentation to discover whether there's a way, in the returned results, to highlight the stems of words that would be returned in an analysis query, but I was not able to find anything in the Solr documentation.

For example, if I use the Solr admin interface to index/query analyze `named beetles running management"` on the Solr sample field `text_en` it results in the last filter, the `PSF`, or PorterStemFilter, changing it to `name beetl run manag`.  I'd like to find a way to query Solr so that it highlights the stems of any found matches.

For example, if my server data contained a phrase

> naming beetles running managers

and I queried using the phrase

> Named beetles running management

it would return the data in solr, `naming beetles running managers` but I would like it to return that matching data highlighted:

> **name**ing **beetle**s **run**ning **manag**ers

because

> **name** **beetle** **run** **manag**

are the stems of the words in my query that match the server data.

Comment: unfortunately, you would need to implement custom highlighting in order to do so

Comment: @Mysterion I don't mind implementing custom highlighting plug in ... I couldn't determine whether there's a way to find the stems to which terms were reduced in the solr db itself.

Comment: I think this task is not trivial, have [a read here](https://medium.com/@sarkaramrit2/tussle-of-highlighting-exact-characters-in-apache-solr-2a48c50dba8c). As soon as you have synonyms any approach to perform partial highlighting comes to an end.

Comment: Maybe post processing is an option? You could perform the analysis of the query terms, store the analysed results and highlight within the response or use a JavaScript highlighter.

Comment: Definitely not trivial.  I think our solution will be to do something like the 3rd comment from @cheffe here.